# How do I get time elapsed since key pressed in SFML?

Tags: c++, keypress, clock, sfml

So I am working on a game using SFML, and I know there is a function `isKeyPressed(key)`, which returns type `bool`.

However I am in need of a way to get the time pressed since the key was first pressed, returning an integer representing the number of milliseconds since that key was first pressed (0 if not currently pressed).

Does such a function exist? If not how would I go about writing one, perhaps using the `sf::Clock` feature?

Comment: What accuracy do you need? Typically the time will be off by ~16ms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would just need to listen for key press events (`sf::Event::KeyPressed`) and start some sort of timer : store the current time in a `sf::Clock` and retrieve the elapsed time with `getElapsedTime()`.

Here is how to listen to events :

```
sf::Event event;
sf::Clock clock;
while (window.pollEvent(event))
{
    if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed) {
        // A key was pressed, start your sf::Clock
        clock.restart();
    }
}
// ...
clock.getElapsedTime();
```

If you want key specific clocks, you need to specify if you want to treat every key like this, many of them, or few.

**Edit** (from your comment) :
If you want to treat every key, you will need an array of `sf::Keyboard::KeyCount` `sf::Clock`'s. Then you can restart clocks of each key independently. Something like this :

```
sf::Event event;
std::array<sf::Clock, sf::Keyboard::KeyCount> keyClocks;
while (window.pollEvent(event))
{
    if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed) {
        // A key was pressed, start this key sf::Clock
        keyClocks[event.key.code].restart();
    }
}
// ...
keyClocks[sf::Keyboard::A].getElapsedTime();
```

Be aware that if you access a key clock which corresponding key has not been pressed, you might get some weird uninitialized stuff, or maybe the time since the declaration of `keyClocks`.

PS : I would personally use the standard library time points and durations because I have not played a lot with SFML, but it does about the same thing. Also, there might be errors in my codes since I have not touched SFML for quite a while.

Comment: Ok thank you. Do you know if there is an easy way to that for every key, like a way to iterate through each key?

Comment: Here you go. Keep in mind that it is a large array (about 100 elements), but since `sf::Clock` is meant to be lightweight, it should not be a problem. There are better solutions for a custom set of keys (e.g I would create an enum similar to `sf::Keyboard::Key`, with less keys).

Comment: thanks a lot! Now all I need to do is make sure the function returns 0 if the key is not pressed, and I should be in good shape :)

Answer (score 0):

SFML has `sf::Clock` that provides a `getElapsedTime()` method. It returns a `sf::Time` object that you can call `asMiliseconds()` on to get the time converted to miliseconds. More info [here](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/system-time.php) and [here](http://sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Time.php).

Comment: Yes, but if you read my question, I am asking for elapsed time since keyboard input.

Comment: So, do some simple maths and subtract the time at which the key was pressed from the current time. Please put a little bit of effort in

Comment: @Yaxlat I am telling you what you would use for that, but Nelxiost has got it right. Check his answer.

Comment: @Bojangles Sorry if I worded my question badly, but I was wondering how I could do that so it works with any key, not just a specific key, I will try to figure it out with events, but I need to find a way to iterate through every key in SFML :)